# HTML Link from Dynamics 365 Dashboard displaying incorrect View Name

Tags: url, dynamics-crm, dashboard, dynamics-365, webresource

The default dashboard for the Dynamics 365 home page contains a list of urls for the user to click.  The list is inside a custom html WebResource containing the links.

[image: Dashboard Links]

When I click on "Natural Gas" it should display the "Gas Division Active Cases" view. It displays the correct data but there is one issue. It displays the wrong view title:

[image: View Title is wrong]

Here is the View in the View manager:

[image: Correct title in View Manager]

The view (compare the "viewId" and "id" from the screens shots) is correct and displays the correctly filtered data. It just has the wrong title.

I attempted several different versions of the URL. Here is the final (relative) url from the WebResource file:

/main.aspx?etn=incident&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={bf88035b-7d1b-e611-80fb-1458d04d78c0}&viewtype=1039

This issue occurs with all five of the dashboard links. Anyone have any suggestions on how to get the correct view title to display on page load?

Comment: Which version is your D365 ? I tried in a 9.1 demo environment with Firefox and it worked as you'd expect, loading the view with the correct title. Verify if using InPrivate and/or a different browser displays the same behavior just to make sure it's not a client issue.

Comment: @Alex - I checked and we are on version 8.2.3.114.  I tried the dashboard in IE, Edge, Chrome and FireFox.  All four browsers had the same behavior.  I also tried the InPrivate on both IE and Chrome with the same result.